# Factorial Combinations - Getting around list size limitation in Java

Tags: java

I have a rather interesting problem - I'm given an input list of points in 3d space and I'm required to output a collection of combinations of these points using the factorial combination equation below:

[image]

where n is the size of the input list of points, and r is the combination length.

For the output, I'm required to produce a list of lists with the sub-list containing the chosen points (size of each sublist being r, and the size of the parent list is the output of 'n choose r')

The problem is that given large enough values of n and r, I start running into the INTEGER.MAXVALUE size limitation for lists in java. E.g. having an input list size of 200 with an 'r' value of 5 will return a value of 2.5 billion - which is already above the max list size.

One way I've thought of to get around this is to split the input list into manageable chunks before I pass it to the combinatorial function:

```
// inputPoints is a List<Point> type
List<List<Point>> inputSplits = Helper.splitInputList(inputPoints) ; // splits input points list so that each subList is a maximum of say 100 in size.

List<List<List<Point>>> outputSplit;

for(var inputListSplit : inputListSplits){
  outputSplit.Add(getCombinations(inputListSplit); // each result will be a List with size smaller than integer.MaxValue. 
}
```

This can work but is inelegant. I've also thought of using linked lists (which apparently don't have a size limit) but haven't looked into the pros and cons of that just yet.

Are there any other ways this could be tackled ? I'm required to produce all possible combination outputs (they don't need to be ordered).

Comment: @ScaryWombat, unfortunately no. Java has a limitation on the max size of an arrayList<> type, which is Integer.maxValue. The number of combinations I can get exceeds this limit

Comment: Creating such a thing is seldom required. Consider implementing `Iterable` to generate the elements sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a java.util.LinkedList, which has (in theory) limitless size.